# Inject existing element into React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject an already existing element on the page into my react DOM in order to wrap around it.

Something like:

```
var someElement = document.getElementById("stuff")
var parent = someElement.parentNode;
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.id = "root1";
parent.replaceChild(wrapper, someElement);
wrapper.appendChild(someElement);

ReactDOM.render(
      <Wrapper child="{{someElement}}" />,
      document.getElementById("root1")
    );
```

I'm not sure how I can go about injecting the element into react + I need the styles of the element to stay as is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use React's **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** method like so:

```
function getHtml(){
    return "<h1>Hello World</h1>" // element.innerHTML (optional)
}


ReactDOM.render(
      <Wrapper> 
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: getHtml() }} />
     </Wrapper>,
      document.getElementById("root1")
    );
```

To add: `<Wrapper/> should render { this.props.children }`

Documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Hope this helps!